# How can I process a list of data for display in the view in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have this list, and I would like to create a sum of each items' data portion, and display this in the view.

```
        //this data    
        var list=[{
                id:1,
                data:[
                    {name:'item 1',qty:100,price:1},
                    {name:'item 2',qty:150,price:1.5}
                ]
            },{
                id:2,


   data:[
                {name:'item 1',qty:100,price:1},
                {name:'item 2',qty:150,price:1.5}
            ]
            }]
```

//this sum fun

```
   function countmoney(l){
            count_listmoney=0;
            for(i=0;i<l.data.length;i++){
                count_listmoney+=l.data[i].price*l.data[i].qty
            }
            return count_listmoney
        }
```

HTML

```
    <div id="viewtable">
            <div ng-repeat="l in list">
<!--Is there an alternative better way?-->
                <div>{{countmoney(l)}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Is there a better way than calling a function from the view like this?

Answer (score 0):

Process your data first, then show it in the view:

```
// ideally in a service
var sums = []

for (var i=0; i < list.length; i++) {
  sums.push(countmoney(list[i]))
}

// controller
$scope.sums = sums; // better:  $scope.sums = dataService.getSums()
```

HTML

```
<div id="viewtable">
   <div ng-repeat="sum in sums">
      <div>{{sum}}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple way**

```
<div id="viewtable">
    <div ng-repeat="l in list">
            Sum : {{l.price*l.qty}}
    </div>
</div>
```